# How to specify ormconfig.ts for TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have created a sample TypeORM project using the TypeORM CLI which has ormconfig.json by default:

```
{
   "type": "postgres",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 5432,
   "username": "postgres",
   "password": "postgres",
   "database": "test",
   "synchronize": false,
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "database/migrations/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "database/migrations",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
}
```

this is the directory structure:

```
-database
  -migrations
-src
  -entity
-ormconfig.json
```

This creates the migrations in the database/migrations folder properly as well as executes the migrations from it.

I replaced ormconfig.json with the following ormconfig.ts :

```
export default {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    username: 'postgres',
    password: 'postgres',
    database: 'test',
    synchronize: false,
    "entities": [
        "src/entity/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "migrations": [
         "database/migrations/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "subscribers": [
        "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "cli": {
        "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
        "migrationsDir": "database/migrations",
        "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
    }
};
```

This however creates migrations in the root directory instead of inside database/migrations.

Can anyone help me in figuring out what's missing here and how I can use ormconfig.ts to generate migrations inside the intended directory?

Comment: I have an issue with this now. have you fixed this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At the time of writing, TypeORM only look for `ormconfig.json` and ignores `ormconfig.ts`. There is [work in progress](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2358) to support it though.

Beside having ormconfig.json you need these commands in your package.json.

```
"typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm",
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate --config src/config/ormconfig.json --connection  --name ",
"migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run"
```

Answer (score 29):

Hey i up this conversation since i can propose you a solution.

You can put the following line in your `package.json` file:

```
"typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config server/environments/database.ts",
```

And your ts config must export directly the config by doing that:

```
export = { /* your config */ };
```

As you can see, you can also specify the path of your config. No need for your config to be at the root level of your project.

Hope that will help you

Answer (score 23):

Just remove the `default` while exporting.
Your `ormconfig.ts` should be something like:

```
import env from './src/env';

export = {
  host: env.DB_CONFIG.host,
  type: 'mysql',
  port: env.DB_CONFIG.port,
  username: env.DB_CONFIG.username,
  password: env.DB_CONFIG.password,
  database: env.DB_CONFIG.database,
  entities: [
    'src/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}',
  ],
  migrations: [
    'src/database/migrations/*.ts',
  ],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/database/migrations',
  },
  synchronize: false,
};
```

In my case I'm using a main `env.ts` file, as the database connection needs to be different depending on the environment.
Also, don't forget using `ts-node` for dealing with `typeorm cli` in `package.json`:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "migrate:create": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:create -n",
    "migrate:up": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run",
    "migrate:down": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:revert"
    ...
  }
...
```

So creating, running or rolling back migrations should be like:

```
npm run migrate:create FileName
npm run migrate:up
npm run migrate:down
```

Comment: Since the `typeorm` package has its `bin` mapped already to `cli.js` you can omit the `cli.js` in those commands. So it's just `ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm ...`

Comment: Can you put you .env file here it would help Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

### Project Structure

```
.
├── src // Typescript files
│   ├── entities
│   │   └── User.ts
│   ├── db
│   │   └── ormconfig.ts
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   └── ... // migration files
├── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
```

### Requirements

- Typeorm should be able to use `src/db/ormconfig.ts` file for connection.
- We should be able to create `migrations`, and perform all typeorm cli supported operations using `src/db/ormconfig.ts` file.

### Possiblility

We might be able to accomplish this using `ts-node` package available for typescript.

### Solution and Github Link

Please checkout https://github.com/devjayantmalik/sample-node-typeorm for complete example.

> Contents of `src/db/ormconfig.ts` file are:

```
import path from "path";
import { ConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";

export default {
  name: "default",
  type: "better-sqlite3",
  database: ":memory:",
  synchronize: true,
  migrationsRun: true,
  dropSchema: false,
  entities: [path.join(__dirname, "..", "entities", "**", "*.*"), path.join(__dirname, "..", "entities", "*.*")],
  migrations: [path.join(__dirname, "migrations", "*.*")],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: path.join(__dirname, "..", "entities"),
    migrationsDir: path.join(__dirname, "migrations")
  }
} as ConnectionOptions;
```

> Script section of `src/db/package.json` file are:

````json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts",
  "build": "tsc",
  "start": "node dist/index.js",
  "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm -f ./src/db/ormconfig.ts",
  "migration:generate": "yarn run typeorm migration:generate -n",
  "migration:blank": "yarn run typeorm migration:create -n"
},```

## Usage

```bash
# Generate a blank migration
yarn migration:blank migration-name-here

# Generate migrations from database and entities.
yarn migration:generate

# Roll back a migration using cli options.
yarn typeorm migration:down
````

Comment: Do you have working repo for the example you provided?.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have one exposed as public.

Comment: could you please please add a minimal working example repo?

Comment: Check github link in Solutions section. I have updated the answer to include github link.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution**

**Specify ormconfig.ts**

```
import { ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';

// Check typeORM documentation for more information.
const config: ConnectionOptions = {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.SQL_IP, // localhost
    port: process.env.SQL_PORT,// 5432
    username: process.env.SQL_USER, // databse login role username
    password: process.env.SQL_PASSWORD, // database login role password
    database: process.env.SQL_DATABASE, // db name

    // entities name should be **.entity.ts
    entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],

    // We are using migrations, synchronize should be set to false.
    // synchronize: process.env.TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE
    //  ? process.env.TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE.toLowerCase() === 'true'
    //  : false,
    synchronize: false,

    // Run migrations automatically,
    // you can disable this if you prefer running migration manually.
    migrationsRun: false,

    logging: false,
    // logger: 'advanced-console',

    // Allow both start:prod and start:dev to use migrations
    // __dirname is either dist or src folder, meaning either
    // the compiled js in prod or the ts in dev.
    migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
    cli: {
        // Location of migration should be inside src folder
        // to be compiled into dist/ folder.
        migrationsDir: 'src/database/migrations'
    }
};

export = config;
```

**In Package.json define this under scripts**

```
"typeorm": "ts-node --files -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config src/database/config.ts"
"db:migrate": "npm run typeorm migration:run",
"db:create-migration": "npm run typeorm migration:create -- -n",
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Yarn 2 with PnP as a package manager, then you can't do exactly the same as others solution here since you don't have a node_modules directory.

Here is how I could make it work:

package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "typeorm": "yarn node -r ts-node/register/transpile-only $(yarn bin typeorm)",
    "generate-migration": "yarn typeorm --config ormconfig.ts migration:generate --check",
  }
  "dependencies": {
     "typeorm": "^0.2.41",
  }
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
  }
}
```

ormconfig.ts

```
/* eslint-disable no-process-env */
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { SnakeNamingStrategy } from 'typeorm-naming-strategies';

dotenv.config();
dotenv.config({ path: './.env.local' });

export = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  entities: ['src/infrastructure/persistence/**/*.entity.ts'],
  migrations: ['src/infrastructure/persistence/migrations/**/*.{ts,js}'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/infrastructure/persistence/migrations',
  },
  namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Took an age, but this got it working for me - build to compile the TS code to a dist file and node to run it. ts-node doesn't want to play well with my project, i think this is pretty clean. nodemon for running it in dev - although i think i need to add ts-node for that / still to work out that compile and run.

ormconfig.ts

```
import { ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';    
export const baseConfig: ConnectionOptions = {
      synchronize: true, // TODO turn false after initial setup i.e. when moving to migrations
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'xxx',
      password: 'xxx',
      database: 'xxx',
      entities: ['dist/Entities/**/**.entity.js'],
      migrations: ['dist/Migrations/*.js'],
      cli: {
        entitiesDir: 'dist/Entities/**/*.js',
        migrationsDir: 'dist/Migrations/*.js'
      }
    };
```

and package.json scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf ./dist && tsc",
    "start": "npm run build && node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts",
    "format:prettier": "prettier --config .prettierrc 'src/**/*.ts' --write",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext .ts --fix",
    "test": "jest --runInBand"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed `omrconfig.json` per `omrconfig.ts`

Then I installed the typeorm CLI global with

`npm i -g typeorm`

And add two scripts in package.json, the first is:

`"typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config server/environments/migrations.ts"`

And the second is:

`"migrate:create": "typeorm migration:create \"./typeorm/migrations/"`

So I managed to save the migrations in the chosen folder inside typeorm/migrations with the terminal command

`npm run migrate:create -n {migrationName}`